# Matplotlib not showing one point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line x log scale but the first point is not being shown although the scale is correct. The value for x == 0 is 1.57 and the value for x == 10^(-8) is 0.4.

How can I correct the plot ?

```
    plt.plot(lambdas, errors, "-b", label = 'Test')
    plt.plot(lambdas,errors_train, "-r", label = 'Train')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")

    plt.xlabel('ln lambda')
    plt.ylabel('Root Mean Squared Error')

    plt.savefig("1.png")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`symlog`](https://matplotlib.org/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.SymmetricalLogScale) scale and set the linear threshold (minimum value below which the scale changes to a linear scale) as needed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1e-8, 1e-7, .1], [1.6, .4, .3, .4])
plt.xscale('symlog', linthresh=1e-8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Values that are strictly equal to zero can't be represented on a log scale because log(0) is not defined.

Comment: Is there a way to do it ? Still plot in log scale but show all the the point corresponding to 0 ?